# Can I receive notifications for my eBay watch list?

Tags: ebay

I am new to eBay. I added some items to my watch list. I would like to know whether I can receive mail notification when something changed with those items.

I couldn't find that option, so does that come by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the eBay help pages](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/buy/watching-items.html):

> **What does it mean to “watch” an item?**
>
> When you’re “watching” an item, the listing appears in your Watching
>   list in My eBay. You can view the item every time you visit My eBay,
>   without having to search for it again.
>
> By watching an item, you can: View the current high bid for the item
>   Place a bid or take another action on the item View the seller’s other
>   items Get notified by email when the status of the listing changes or
>   if the item gets relisted

If you haven't amended any account settings that you will real-time alerts for items being watched.  To check your preferences you need to:

Log in to eBay > Account Settings > Communication Preferences.

In the `Buyer` section expand the `Buying activity` section.  You will then be able to change the frequency of the emails.

[image: eBay Comm prefs]